# Symfony 2 : dev to pro = blank page

Tags: php, symfony, production

first I took you to excuse my English. 
I made a website with Symfony which works fine locally. (dev and prod). 
But as soon as I put online the dev version works but the prod version displays a blank page. 
Lighttpd does not give me error. 
PHP does not give me error. 
Cache and log are writable.

I do not understand anything.

Comment: Can you check HTTP response (in Chrome Developer Toolbar) when you get a blank page?

Comment: Seems like you just have to clear your cache `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` or just remove everything manually in the `app/cache/` folder.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error T_T

Comment: Seems like you just have to clear your cache php app/console cache:clear --env=prod or just remove everything manually in the app/cache/ folder -> nothing change

Comment: Does your web server have permissions to write to the cache folders on the production server? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions

Comment: Yes log and cache have permissions. [ls -l link](http://pastebin.com/8ECk7Acb)

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is highly undesirable situation as you need to squash bugs one-by-one. It could be as benign as missing php module or some major `httpd` misconfiguraion.

Some steps that should shed some light on the issue:

1. Fire up the `Terminal` (you do have `ssh` access, right?)
2. Check logs (both `httpd` and `symfony`)

<kbd>httpd log:</kbd>

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

... and refresh your page

<kbd>Symfony</kbd>

```
tail -f /path-to-your-symfony-app/app/logs/prod.log
```

... again, refresh your page

In your comment, you said you encountered `HTTP500` error. Is that Apache's or Symfony's `HTTP500`?

If you do not hape `ssh` access upload your `app_dev.php` and run it directly. Be sure to add your IP address to list of allowed (within the file)

Comment: I use ssh access.
I looked at the log file lighttpd and nothing changes when I reload the page. 
I do not have a dev.log but just a prod.log for symfony.

Comment: And how about `access_log` of your lighttpd? Sorry, I'm a bit unfamiliar about log names in `lighttp`...

Comment: My log in prod : [log file](http://pastebin.com/pvL7f1si) and my log in dev : [log file](http://pastebin.com/btFwiTqP)

Answer (score 1):

Change your permission on cache and log folders in `777`.

```
chmod 777 cache/ log/ -R
php symfony cc
```

Comment: It was just chmodding `app/cache/` and `app/logs/` for me

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#running-the-symfony-application) says:

Instead of the Welcome Page, you may see a blank page or an error page. This is caused by a directory permission misconfiguration. There are several possible solutions depending on your operating system. All of them are explained in the Setting up Permissions section.

And then you should follow [these steps](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions):

1. `rm -rf app/cache/*`
2. `rm -rf app/logs/*`
3. `HTTPDUSER=' ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1'`
4. `sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:'whoami':rwX app/cache app/logs`
5. `sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:'whoami':rwX app/cache app/logs`

Answer (score 0):

I did the  deployment as guided in this [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html)

In my case the update of symfony before deploying was not BC with an old Bundle, so the clear:cache --env=prod was giving some error. So what I did was to manually delete the prod cache and then clear:cache with the prod environment and it worked: so to resume:

```
#rm -rf app/cache/prod/*  #removes only production cache
rm -rf app/cache/   #removes prod and any other stage cache
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```